# QGIS actions: copy to clipboard some attributes

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, actions

**When I click on "execute action entity"

=>Copy to clipboard a preconfigured set of attributes of my layer.**

Here's what I've done so far:

- Open the Layer Properties dialog and head over to the Actions tab
- Set up a new action using the following properties for the action

  Type: Windows
  Name: Copy Attribute
  Action :  "copy to clipboard [%name%] - [%value1%] - [%value2%]"

but I'm not familiar with actions script semantic.

what would be the correct redaction of the action code above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could choose action-type Python and do something like this:

```
from PyQt4.Qt import QApplication
clipboard = QApplication.clipboard()
clipboard.setText("[% "name"%]"+","+str([% "myintegerfield"%]))
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for your quick answer, works well. I just had to remove the str() since I had a syntax error...

Comment: Hi all! I need to copy some attribute values in some fields of a layer, and paste these automatically in another layer, which have the same fields. This script could work? Can you explain briefly how this "action" works? Thanks a lot.